# Assign Array values to object Array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, object, assign

I have the following problem:

```
[obj(:).Radius] = arrayOfRadius;
```

I have an Array with radius for every single object. The upper code doesn't work though the object has the same size as the right hand arrayOfRadius.

I could solve this with a for loop, sure:

```
for i = 1:length(obj)
   obj(i).Radius = arrayOfRadius(i);
end
```

That's not the way I'd like to solve it. I already found the "deal" function. But the deal function copies the whole arrayOfRadius() in every object.

Can someone help me out?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the more obnoxious areas of MATLAB's indexing that I really wish they would fix, especially with the move of graphics handles to objects from doubles making it non-intuitive how to set properties of multiple objects at the same time.

There exists a workaround for [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html), though it requires the intermediate use of [`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html):

```
% Initialize a structure
obj(6).radius = 6;

radii = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
C = num2cell(radii);
[obj(:).radius] = deal(C{:});
```

Which returns:

```
>> [obj.radius]

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6
```

As desired.

Comment: Hehehe 20 seconds away from each other. Nicely done.

Answer (score 4):

A very hacky solution would be to take the array and turn it into a cell array, then use a comma-separated list to finally do the assignment.  Assuming that `obj` is already declared, do something like this:

```
A = num2cell(arrayOfRadius);
[obj.Radius] = A{:};
```

[`num2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) converts the array into a cell array of individual elements and doing `A{:}` converts the cell array into a comma-separated list and we'll deal out each element into its respective slot in the structure.  Doing `obj.Radius` unpacks each `Radius` field in your structure into a comma-separated list.  Therefore the above code is equivalent to doing:

```
[obj(1).Radius, obj(2).Radius, ..., obj(N).radius] = A(1), A(2), ..., A(N)
```

`N` is the total number of elements in `arrayOfRadius`.

### Reproducible example

```
>> clear
>> obj(4).Radius = 0;
>> disp([obj.Radius])
     0

>> arrayOfRadius = [1 2 3 4];
>> A = num2cell(arrayOfRadius);
>> [obj.Radius] = A{:};
>> disp([obj.Radius])
     1     2     3     4
```

### My Two Cents...

FWIW, using the `for` loop approach is actually more readable.  Doing this workaround really makes the code obfuscated... especially if you're only copying elements from an array to a structure.  How many times is this copying going to be performed?  If it's only once or a few times, stick with the `for` loop for readability.

Comment: Thank you very much, too! The procedure repeats very often with a lot of elements. The for loop is significantly slower in that case, so I want to do the "fast" version with that approach.

Comment: @Diluvian ah I see.  In that case, use `num2cell` and comma-separated lists.  Good luck!